# code coverage just 15% for batch scheduled apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, schedulebatch

Can anyone help me out in this issue which I am facing code coverage for scheduled batch apex.
My batch class is below

```
global class BatchImpliedConsentAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {
global integer recordsProcessed = 0;

public static void scheduleImpliedConsentAccountBatch(){
    System.schedule('Implied Consent Account Job', '0 10 0 * * ?', new BatchImpliedConsentAccount());
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext context){
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchImpliedConsentAccount());
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Implied_Consent__pc,IsPersonAccount,Implied_Consent_Date__pc,PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail,CASL_Opt_In__pc,CASL_Opt_In_Status__pc, Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc from Account WHERE Implied_Consent__pc != null AND Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc != null AND Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc.date() <= system.today() LIMIT 10000 ' );
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope){
    for(Account l: scope){
        //date d = l.Implied_Consent_Expiry__c.date();
        if((l.Implied_Consent__pc == true) && (l.Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc.date() <= system.today()) ){
            l.Implied_Consent_Date__pc = null;
            l.Implied_Consent__pc = false;
            l.PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = true;
            l.CASL_Opt_In__pc = false;
            l.CASL_Opt_In_Status__pc = 'Removed';

        }
    }
    AccountCASLClass.FreezeCASLonAccounttrigger=true;
    update scope;
    AccountCASLClass.FreezeCASLonAccounttrigger=false;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        system.debug(recordsProcessed +'records Processed');
        AsyncApexJob job = [select Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems,CreatedBy.Email         from AsyncApexJob where Id =: bc.getJobId()];
}

}
```

I tried below test class but I am getting just 15% of code coverage.

```
    @isTest
    public class TestClassforBatchImpliedConsentAccount {
    static testMethod void BatchImpliedConsentAccount(){
    Id RecordTypeIdAccount = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Person Account').getRecordTypeId();
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.LastName = 'Test1';
    acc.Language__pc = 'English';
    acc.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeIdAccount;
    acc.Implied_Consent__pc = true;
    acc.Implied_Consent_Source__pc = 'General Inquiry – Web';
    acc.Implied_Consent_Date__pc = datetime.newInstance(2014, 9, 15, 12, 30, 0);
    acc.Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc = system.now().addDays(-20);
    AccountCASLClass.FreezeCASLonAccounttrigger = true;
    insert acc;
    system.debug('acc details are :' + acc.Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc );
    AccountCASLClass.FreezeCASLonAccounttrigger = false;
    test.startTest();
    AccountCASLClass.FreezeCASLonAccounttrigger = true;
    BatchImpliedConsentAccount obj = new BatchImpliedConsentAccount();
    String sch = '0 10 0 * * ?';
    system.schedule('Test Territory Check', sch, obj);
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(obj);
    AccountCASLClass.FreezeCASLonAccounttrigger = false;
    test.stopTest();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should fail. You can't execute Apex statements in dynamic SOQL:

```
'... Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc.date() <= system.today() ...'
```

You can't even do the part on the left without causing issues, as you'd have to use a date formula, not just arbitrary Apex.

Also, your batch could be optimized to process fewer records by changing your filters.

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
  SELECT Id 
  from Account WHERE IsPersonAccount = true and 
    Implied_Consent__pc = true AND
    Implied_Consent_Expiry__pc <= today
]);
```

From there, you don't need to both schedule the job and execute the batch; doing the scheduling should cause the batch to kick off just fine.